# How to Sort Laravel collection groupBy results in asc order

Tags: laravel

I am just running a query in Laravel using a query builder as follows.

```
        $query = \DB::table('units_amenities_values')
            ->join('units', 'units.id', 'units_amenities_values.unit_id')
            ->join('floors', 'floors.id', 'units.floor_id')
            ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', 'floors.building_id')
            ->join('properties', 'properties.id', 'buildings.property_id')
            ->leftJoin('amenity_values', 'amenity_values.id', 'units_amenities_values.amenity_value_id')
            ->leftJoin('amenities', 'amenities.id', 'amenity_values.amenity_id')
            ->select('units_amenities_values.id as uav_id', 'amenities.id as amenity_id', 'amenities.amenity_name', 'amenity_values.amenity_value', 'floors.floor','units.id as unit_id', 'units.unit_number','units.unit_rent', 'units.stack', 'amenities.category_id', 'buildings.id as building_id')
            ->where('buildings.property_id',2)
            ->orderBy('units.unit_number','asc');
        $data = $query->get();
        $grouped = $data->groupBy('building_id');
```

This works without error, however, the result is not in the way as I intended. This is grouping in descending order.

I tried by adding `->orderBy('buildings.id','asc')` before as well as after `orderBy('units.unit_number','asc')`. This makes does not make any difference. Also, tried by adding `orderBy('building_id','asc')` with groupBy as well, but it throws error as `orderBy does not exist`.

Is there anything that I could do, to get the results as my preference.

By the way, the `$grouped` looks like:

```
<pre>Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [7] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [uav_id] => 5557
                                    ...
                                    ...
                                    [building_id] => 7
                                )
                            [1] => ...
                            [2] => ...
                        )
                )
            [6] => ...
            [5] => ...
            [4] => ...
            ...
        )
)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have given several examples I'm not sure what order you want the results in. Do you want the results ordered by buildings_id, or unit_number or both?

The query you have shown will order the results by unit_number (although you have failed to show this value in you output).

The `->groupBy()` method takes the building_id from your results and creates a new key - but doesn't reorder your collection, so it's still ordered by unit_number.

If you want to return a collection ordered by building_id, use `->orderBy('building_id', 'asc')`  which will return an ordered collection. If you iterate through it, it will be in the correct order.

If you prefer a plain array, use

`$array = $data->toArray()`

If you want to keep the grouping (with the extra key), then use

`$grouped = $data->sortBy('building_id')->groupBy('building_id')`